# Install mysql version 5.5 through terminal

Tags: mysql, terminal, rubygems, rvm, osx-lion

Where can I find the `~/.rvmrc file`. I have to put `rvm_archflags="-arch x86_64"` there as in the tutorial http://beginrescueend.com/integration/databases/. Also, is there any other way to install mysql 5.5 through terminal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the file is not there, just create it ;)

Comment: but where? I couldn't find the file through spotlight, but it might be there(because rvm is installed)? Isn't it?

Comment: No, it wouldn't ... Just open a Terminal and open the file using your favorite command line editor... For example `vim ~/.rvmrc` ... And if you just need to add that one line to the file do the following: `echo 'rvm_archflags="-arch x86_64"'>~/.rvmrc`

Comment: did that, but `sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config` doesn't work after that